# Swift MVC model for Firestore ( learning the MVC model )

Tags: swift, firebase, model-view-controller

I know how to implement firestore/authentication/storage from firebase, but I do not know how to implement it using the MVC model. I just rewrite this or similar code on each View Controller.

```
// Old way

import Firebase

@IBOutlet weak var nametextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailtextfield: UITextField!

let db = Firestore.firestore()
let uidUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
var documentDirectory: [String: Any] = [
    var name:  "",
    var email: "",
    var date:  ""
]

func firestore {
    if let userName = nametextField.text, let userEmail = emailtextfield.text, let uid = uidUser {
        self.documentDirectory.updateValue(userName, forKey: name )
        self.documentDirectory.updateValue(userEmail, forKey: email )
        self.documentDirectory.updateValue(FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), forKey: date )
        let documentReference = self.db.collection("User Info").document(uid)
        documentReference.setData(self.documentDirectory) { (error) in
            if let err = error {
                print("Error saving to DB \(err.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Worked")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
// New way
import Firebase
class FirestoreClass {

static func firestoreCallBack(name: String, email: String, uid: 
String, documentDirectory: [String: Any], collectionName: String) {
var localDictionary = dict
let documentReference = 
Firestore.firestore().collection(collectionName).document(uid)
documentReference.setData(localDictionary){ (error) in
if let err = error {
print("Error saving to DB \(err.localizedDescription)")
} else {
print("Worked")
   }
  }    
 }
}



// method callback
import Firebase

@IBOutlet weak var nametextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailtextfield: UITextField!

let db = Firestore.firestore()
let uidUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

func firestore {
if let userName = nametextField.text, let userEmail = 
emailtextfield.text, let uid = uidUser {

var dict: [String: Any] = [
    var name:          userName,
    var email:         userEmail,
    var date:          FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
]

FirestoreClass.firestoreCallBack(name: userName, email: userEmail, 
uid:uid, documentDirectory: dict, collectionName: ""User Info"")
 }
}
```

This code will create a document with 3 fields ( name, email and the date the document was created ). I think the 'New way' will work as the MVC model. The Primary objective was to use a Class/Struct to have a template to recall the Firestore entry in different parts of an app.

Comment: Your M in MVC should be a struct (or class) that replaces the documentDirectory dictionary and you should move the firestore func and similar to a specific service class that handles the communication with the database so you do not have that code in your controller

Comment: The question is unclear. The code in your question belongs in a controller (mostly) but there is no View or Model shown per se. What specifically are you attempting to accomplish and why? In other word,  telling us you want to implement something using MVC and then showing some code doesn't really give us much to go on. Also, formatting your code is really important here on SO, so please take time to use the formatting tools to make your code readable (and pretty!).

Comment: @Jay It's basically taking the func firestore and putting the blueprint into a Struct or Class. The purpose is to recall the func firestore in different parts of the app. I'll edit and update the question better.

Comment: *recall the func firestore in different parts of the app* why? This really sounds like you're asking about a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) which (IMO) falls slightly outside of MVC and there may be better options. Also, the function `firestoreCallBack` doesn't call back. Most importantly, Firebase is asynchronous so you'll need to code it that way. Lastly, the code formatting in the question makes is difficult to read - please take time to use the code formatting tools in the toolbar to properly format code so it's readable. Update and we'll take a look!

Comment: @Jay I tried the formatting ( pressed cmd+K ) but it basically didn't affect the code. Is there another way you want the code formatted? If it's due to the long lines going into another line, I cannot help it due to the width of the textfield. I didn't use a Singleton because I used static on the 'firestoreCallBack' method. If I can understand how to use the MVC properly, I can then recall the 'template' for firebase firestore, auth and storage anywhere in an app and also general methods.

Comment: I formatted the top section of your code for you so you can see the difference. While you can use a singleton pattern or a class, it's challenging with Asynchronous API's and functions like firebase because they do not return values. Another issue is being able to track and remove observers via their handlers - for example if a view goes out of scope and you want to remove the observer. Generally speaking, if your firebase function is outside you're c)ontroller then it's outside the MVC pattern so it's not really applicable. Maybe if you can provide a more concrete example we could help.